# Is there a checkinstall option equivalent to -j in make?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-managers, debian-based

The `sudo checkinstall` command is great for building from source into a debian package so that it's easily removed later. However, what it replaces, `sudo make install`, has an option to split the installation across multiple CPUs if available. For example, to use 4 cores, one can call

```
sudo make install -j4
```

`sudo checkinstall -j4` gives an error that `-j` is an unrecognized option. Is there an equivalent option for `checkinstall`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last (optional) input argument to checkinstall is the install command to execute. If the command is make, then this can be parallelized for example as

```
checkinstall make -j4 install
```

Though, since checkinstall should be run as root, it could be more advisable to first compile and then checkinstall, i.e.

```
make -j4 && sudo checkinstall
```